# BuddyPress 2.8.2 Template Customization Giving Blank Page

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am trying to customize profile-loop.php in Buddypress plugin but it is giving just a header, footer, and blank content area.

Actually, I have checked and it is giving blank content are when I add `add_theme_support( 'buddypress' );` to my `functions.php` file.

If I don't add it then nothing happens with the template update and seem doesn't consider my customization and loading BP Default template files.

So here what I have done.

Copied profile-loop.php from

```
buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/memebers/single/profile/profile-loop.php
```

to

```
mytheme/buddypress/members/single/profile/profile-loop.php
```

However, nothing works.

Please provide me any suggestion or help on it. Thanks...

Comment: You don't need to add theme support.  Is your theme also bundling BP templates?  If so, overloads won't work.  Switch to a WP theme like 2015 for testing.